# Colors make everything fun

Tags: pattern, visual

Can you find what comes next?

[image]

<sub>PS. This is my first puzzle post, feedback is greatly appreciated. Coincidentally, this is a spoof off of the first puzzle I solved that piqued my interest in puzzling/riddles.</sub>

Comment: RR
OR
RORR
RRROOR 
for people having B/W monitor/eyes..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is

> The [look and say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence), with each 1 colored red and each 2 colored orange.

The next in the sequence would be

> 312211, which would be colored yellow(?) red orange orange red red
>
>  [image: look and say sequence]

Comment: Beat me by 20 seconds :P

Comment: Exactly. I remembered this from @Bill the Lizard http://www.billthelizard.com/2017/04/what-is-next-number-in-sequence.html article a month ago.